# Best way of use of ajax in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am using ajax in my cakephp application by using JS helper.so I do not required to write jquery code.
Js helper automatically add the code in my file.Following is the line by which JS helper write the code.

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=>true));
```

When I set the true value of cache attribute,every time a new js file created in js folder and a new script is added in my code in following manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>
```

But when I change the cache value to false,all the js code added in my file line by line.

Now my question is, which way is best way by which,page execution fast.
And my second question is that when I set true value of the cache, js file add only once, right now js helper add the js file again and again,when page is reload or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

For the record this question could have been worded far better.

First question, execution speed:  Saving a new file for every bit of JS probably isn't the way to go.  Hopefully the code below should explain a better way and render your second question moot.

```
// In /app/View/Layouts/default.ctp
...
<head>
 ...
  <?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>
 ...
</head>
<body>
 ...
  <?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); 
 ...
</body>
```

Once that's in place, you can add a script file to your views or layouts with

`<?php echo $this->Html->script('scriptname', array('inline'=>false)); ?>`

(note no .js extension)

Or add custom Js:

```
<?php
    $customJs = "alert('Hi!');";
    echo $this->Html->scriptBlock($customJs, array('inline'=>false));
?>
```

Hope that helps.